# Image max-width not working in media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm having an issue with max-width/max-height inside of media queries.  Basically what's happening is I have an image gallery that uses jQuery to display a modal window. This modal window consists of the modal, a content box, and an image viewer which has some buttons inside for navigation thru images). I have the max-width/max-height set in vw and vh in css but the exit button gets cut off on a mobile device.

Current CSS:

```
#photoViewer {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 0;
height: 0;
transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

#photoViewer img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
max-height: 70vh;
max-width: 70vw;
}
```

I tried using a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 955px) {
   #photoViewer img {
      max-width: 50vw;
      max-height: 50vh;
   }
}
```

but it's not changing anything. I found if set hard "width" and "height" rules it works but the max- seems to throw it off.  Any ideas?

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates kind of what I'm working with (my whole code is pretty large):

https://jsfiddle.net/jessereitz1/6nxg21a3/3/

Comment: can you post your markup too?

Comment: Try using % for the media queries rather than viewport ...

Comment: @MichaelCoker I just added a jsfiddle that has a snippet of what I'm working with.

Comment: @davvv I tried that but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in the fiddle you posted it works:

The images' original sizes there are only 200x133px or vice versa. With  `max-width`/ `max-height` values they will never get larger than their original size.

Only if the screen/viewport becomes less than 400px wide, the `max-width: 50%` will have an effect (for landscape mode images, that is - portrait even less: narrower than 266px).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help and insight. I just found the biggest bug anyone can find in their code: human error and stupidity. I found I had placed an identical CSS rule at the bottom of my code setting the img max-height/width to 90vh/vw. I can now say I've learned to scroll through ALL my code before hopping on here! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI...
Another human error to watch out for that wastes a lot of time due to sometimes working and sometimes not is when media queries are listed in the wrong order.

Sometimes they can get out of order unexpectedly, especially when changing from min to max or vice versa.

When using max-width, check to make sure all queries appear largest to smallest width (1200px, then 992px, etc).

When using min-width, check to make sure all queries appear smallest width to largest (576px, then 768px etc).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you have a `min-height` set on that element, which would override your `max-height` setting.